# Adding rowspan cells onto the end of a table

Tags: html

[image: http://puu.sh/mjgya/d1c9532e71.png]

I'm wanting to make a table with separations using the rowspan attribute, and then in the last column have a total amount that would need to be the same rowspan as the first 3 columns. I could probably just make a couple of dummy cells and make them invisible, but I was wondering what the correct way to go about this would be. I've done a bit of searching but I'm definitely not thinking of the right keywords to use. Sorry if this is obvious, can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: You have a `rowspan` in the first three table columns. Did you compute that or is it hard-coded?

Comment: Yes, the first 3 columns have a rowspan of 6. This is static every time. 3 columns with a rowspan of 6, 2 columns with a rowspan of 1 filled out, and then a last column with a rowspan of 6, but I don't know how to insert that last column.

Comment: as Shown by Serge, You need only add it to the top row you wish to have it be displayed at. It fills in left to right, top to bottom. By having 3 Rowspans, then 2 no rowspans, then a final rowspan Column, he leaves 2 columns worth of room in the table, which for the next 5 rows will be filled in by the first 2 <td> elements.  a third <td> in those rows will be tacked onto the end, in a new 7th column, because the 6th is occupied by a rowspan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not very sure what you are looking for but I gave it a try:

```css
table {
  border: solid 1px black;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 2px 5px 2px 5px
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>[]
    </td>
    <td>App Name
    </td>
    <td>App ID
    </td>
    <td>Add Type
    </td>
    <td>Impressions
    </td>
    <td>App Impressions
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">[]
    </td>
    <td rowspan="5">Name #1
    </td>
    <td rowspan="5">17
    </td>
    <td>Appwall
    </td>
    <td>2,901
    </td>
    <td rowspan="5"> ???
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Banner
    </td>
    <td>2,901
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Dialogue
    </td>
    <td>2,901
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Landing Page
    </td>
    <td>2,901
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Selfpromotion
    </td>
    <td>2,901
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: That's just what I was looking for, thanks! I'm having issues making this work with datatables however.. but that's a problem for another time.